# Конвертор из pdf и docx в html

Tags: html, pdf, docx

На работе разрабы сделали базу знаний на php + angular. А старая база в виде документов docx и pdf.
Подскажите, есть ли эффективный способ перегнать документы в html с сохранением форматирования, картинок, таблицу и прочего?
А пополнять базу в полуручном режиме, сильно грустно(

Буду признателен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из того, что мне известно - можно попробовать онлайн конвертер Convertio. Правда код будет прочитать сложно. Однако для быстрого переноса из doc/docx в html, без последующего редактирования (только чтение) думаю пойдёт. Попробуйте на тестовом документе.

https://convertio.co/ru/docx-html/

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо за подсказку! Сервис действительно хорош, а API стоит не дорого